# Have full control but cannot manage alerts

Tags: alert, library

I have full control for my sharepoint site and I am attempting to set up alerts for folders in one of the libraries. I only have the option to set alerts for myself and not others. Not sure why this is the case. Is there something else I need to set up to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you have the Manage Alerts permission at the site collection level (by default only for the Owners group, I believe). If you have full control at the site level, I'd double check the permission levels to confirm the full control permission level hasn't been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to site collection settings and check any customized permission level is created and manage alerts is not ticked and you have that permissions. Or check with the sharepoint version installed. Or check if the folder which you are trying is not stopped inheriting with top level permission and u might not have the full control permission over there. Just check with all the permissions you own. This will definitely resolve your problem.